# Avoid execute function body pararally by user events until finishes previously triggered execution - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

In my component implementation, *doSomething* function is triggered on a user button click. The problem is that *doSomething* takes around 200-1100ms to complete execution with a state change. I face the problem where rapid button clicks trigger this function body simultaneously which causes unexpected final states.

I **don't require a complex mutual exclusion solution**. The requirement is just to ignore all other calls until the current execution finishes, I tried the following flagging approach:

```
doSomething = () => {
    if(this.running){
        return //ignore the event
    }
    this.running=true;
    //do processing
    this.setState({someVariable:answer_of_process}, ()=>this.running=false);
}

render(){
    return(<ImportedComponent doSomething={this.doSomething}/>)
}
```

This made the probability of state corruption lesser but, occasionally it happens.ie: *before 20% now 2%* . How do I improve this solution to be 0% of the failure rate?

**Edited:**
The function triggering button is from an imported complex component and it cannot be disabled. The component takes *doSomething* as a prop.

Comment: disable the button on click?

Comment: How is `doSomething ` ? Is that via a button click or by an anchor tag or by any other means?

Comment: disable the button and enable the button you can even hide the button using display none

Comment: Is your button component is a react component too? 
I mean can it accept props?

Comment: don't have direct programmatical access to the button.

Comment: yes you have, no matter what the framework is, you always have direct access to button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you need only the last action proceeds in a certain period of time after multiple events been fired.

That belongs to the field of **debounce** function.

> Creates a debounced function that delays invoking function until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced function was invoked.

---

For example: if the user inputs very quickly, and request costs times, we want only the last user input value been fired.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

const request = debounce(value => {
  alert(`request: ${value}`);
}, 1000);

export default function App() {
  // const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const debouceRequest = useCallback(value => request(value), []);
  const onChange = e => {
    // setInput(e.target.value);
    debouceRequest(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={onChange} />
      {/* {input} */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit elated-dawn-lb5ex]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the issue, I adapted the solution from the marked answer for this question with minimum edits :

```
const _ = require('lodash');

doSomething = _.debounce(() => {
    if(this.running){
        return //ignore the event
    }
    this.running=true;
    //do processing
    this.setState({someVariable:answer_of_process}, ()=>this.running=false);
}, 500)

render(){
    return(<ImportedComponent doSomething={this.doSomething}/>)
}
```